# How is there a dataframe constructor error?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
Address
Zutphenseweg 5 7418 AW VENLO
```

when using this code to order the values:

```
# structuring postalcode, city, address for invoice maker
df['Postalcode2p'] = df['Address'].fillna('7418 A')
df['Postalcode2'] = df['Address'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d{4}.[A-Z]{2})')
df['Postalcode3']= df['Address'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d{5})')
df['Postalcode4']=df['Address'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d{4}[A-Z]{2})')
df['Postalcode_Final'] = df['Postalcode2'].where(df['Postalcode2'].notnull(), df['Postalcode3'])
df['Postalcode_Final'] = df['Postalcode_Final'].where(df['Postalcode_Final'].notnull(), df['Postalcode4'])
df = df.drop(['Postalcode2','Postalcode3','Postalcode4'],axis=1)
df['Postalcodestring'] = df.Postalcode_Final.str.extract('(\d+)')
#NL
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]    
#DE
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'City2'] = nomi2.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-9a016dffb57b> in <module>
     67 #NL
     68 for i, row in df.iterrows():
---> 69     df.loc[i, 'City1'] = nomi.query_postal_code(df['Postalcodestring'][i])[2]
     70 #DE
     71 for i, row in df.iterrows():
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Please help

Comment: Just clarifying, are you trying to set some values? If so, let me know, I can provide an answer that would be a better approach overall. If not, no worries, I'll still try to help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment zerecees, I'm indeed trying to instill values into "city1" based on Postalcodestring column.